# Is it possible to allocate one executor per node to run spark tasks

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, scheduler

I have total of 50 node cluster, I have usecase where i want to run spark program in parallel in different machine or IP addresses.
Is it possible to configure spark to launch only one executor per node with any configurations ?

Comment: This should help you :https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html